# Zipping large directory on Windows Server using PHP

Tags: php, zip, windows-server

I want to zip a large folder of 50K files on Windows Server. I'm currently using this code:

```
include_once("CreateZipFile.inc.php");
$createZipFile=new CreateZipFile;

$directoryToZip="repository";
$outputDir=".";
$zipName="CreateZipFileWithPHP.zip";

define("ZIP_DIR",1); //


if(ZIP_DIR)
{
//Code toZip a directory and all its files/subdirectories
$createZipFile->zipDirectory($directoryToZip,$outputDir);
}else
{
//?
}

$fd=fopen($zipName, "wb");
$out=fwrite($fd,$createZipFile->getZippedfile());
fclose($fd);
$createZipFile->forceDownload($zipName);
@unlink($zipName);
```

Everything works fine until around 2K image files. But this is not what I want to get. I'm willing to process to zip like 50K images at least. Meanwhile my script gets this error:

> Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 360 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\htdocs\filemanager\CreateZipFile.inc.php on line 92

```
$newOffset = strlen(implode("", $this->compressedData));
```

I'm searching for any solution to proceed such a huge amount of files. I currently use XAMPP on Windows Server 2008 Standard. Is there any possibility to make small parts of the zips, use a system command and maybe external tool to pack them and then send it to header to download?

http://pastebin.com/iHfT6x69 for CreateZipFile.inc.php

Comment: Consider setting up a job server, using something like Gearman.

Comment: Sounds nice but setting this up can be hard for me:(

Comment: Why? Get yourself a VPS and it can be installed with a few commands. If you don't know how to, then you can learn; this is technology worth learning.

Comment: Ok clets consider Gearman it would work there?

Comment: Err yes, that's why I suggested it `:)`. Gearman runs as a daemon (a background process) and you set up a bunch of workers that do the background work. If you have a proper zip library, you may be able to read a percentage zipped, which can be used be the worker to report progress to Gearman, and in your online application you can (a) start jobs, (b) check the status of jobs, and (c) see how complete jobs are as a percentage. It's robust and there's plenty of docs on it. I use it for rendering documents and crawling the web - anything you can't do in an online app.

Comment: Do you have any clue where to find that proper zip library?

Comment: You do need to be willing to do some research on this problem! Yes, you can use [php.net/zip](http://php.net/zip). Since files can be added individually, the percentage complete is just `(files_added / files_total) * 100`.

Comment: I might pay for have this script done and that works

Answer (score 0):

try this .. to increase execution time

`ini_set('max_execution_time', 500);`

500 is number os seconds change it to whatever you lilke

Comment: This isn't the case why would I let someone wait that long on a site. It should probably somehow run "in background" :s and for sure 500s wouldn't be enough with this code.

Comment: As far as I know there is no "in the background" with php. If you want to continue using PHP you could however look into [cron jobs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron), which allow you to periodically execute certain tasks. This would probably still require @Zeedias solutions though(if it works :P).

Comment: you can make 5000. but anyway the user must wait for the server response. even if you running your code the background. it all depends on your machine .

Comment: Well what about the cron jobs any examples out there my friend? I was considering making a pop-up window for the process. Really this case makes me sick :((

Comment: I would need a bounty on that question though.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need a smaller file or a fast served file?
for fast serving without compression and without memory leak you could try to use the system command with a zip software like gzip and turning the compression of.

the files would probably get huge but would be served fast as one file.

Comment: I searched and barely can find any gzip scripts for packing do you have 1 maybe?

Comment: try something like this: 
install GnuZip on your server
run:
system('path/to/gzip -1 nameofdirectory', $retval)
with this you will pack your the files in the directory to one .gz file
the other arguments of GNUZip are well documented in the help.
hope this will help you.

Comment: Well how to is it? system('gzip', $retval) I never used such command

Comment: With system u write a command to system like in console/bat

these commands wouldn't use ur task/thread of your php
they run themself and don't use the memory of your php

gzip you have to install separetly and than run it from php
it would process your zip file

not sure how big it would be

i'm useng node.js - used php before but never did that much files in zipping just a few... didn't like the response times of php

Comment: I installed node and configurated it good i think and when i type in cmd $ npm install adm-zip it shows me ... under it why?

Comment: in cmd you don't have to write the $
that's linux console syntax
just write: npm install adm-zip.

But that was not the point of my last comment. I don't think, it's a good idea to switch from php to node just to solve just one problem.

try to run a zip tool with the system-command in php [php-manual](http://us1.php.net/manual/en/function.system.php).
And try to turn off the compression - would be much faster THAN COMPRESSING THE FILES.

Comment: No idea what tool to use and how can u help:( I googled a lot up and nothing please:s

Comment: I got echo system("tar -cvzpf $path_to_backup_file 2>&1"); but it returns that he don't know the tar command:S